How to allow some customers to bypass the website .htaccess
My website www.attractionsofchina.com a strict .htaccess file, that blocks countries like Russia or vietnam. Some of my clients, may - on occasion - travel to such countries.
What is the easiest/safest way to just let someone bypass the .htaccess rules?

You would need to be able to somehow "recognize" those users. If they can't access your site at all from those locations, then you would have to agree with them on some sort of specific request characteristic they need to provide, beforehand. (Could be a specific request header set via a browser extension, or an added URL parameter, or similar things.)

One should note however that such bypassing mechanisms usually mean bypassing all security measurements. So "the easiest/safest way" is a contradiction in itself.

Easiest would probably be to use a VPN in those occasions that terminates outside of country zones you want to deny access to. Ideally on that server itself or maybe within a corporate network. That would not bypass security, since you have control over who can setup such VPN tunnel.
